# How to set alpha channel of GlSurfaceView

Tags: android, view, opengl-es, alpha, glsurfaceview

I can not to set alpha parameter for my `GlSurfaceView`. XML-attribute `android:alpha=` not working, call of method from code `mView.setAlpha()` too not working. I read about a similar problem, for example, - how to make a transparent background on this `View`, but unfortunately solution did not help to solve my problem - to set alpha channel the contains of `GlSurfaceView`. I tried to move `GlSurfaceView` inside `FrameLayout` and yet to set alpha of `FrameLayout`, but this solution did not help.

Now i am still see only a one variant - to move a sample View above `GlSurfaceView` and to set a transparent of a sample `View`. This solution to be last case for me!

**I want to ask** - Is there any way to solve this problem differently?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing source code enables members to offer more helpful advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is solved!**

Only one variant is correct - to set parametr *'alpha'* in *'gl_FragColor'* of your shader! For example: `gl_FragColor.a=0.5;`

That to have acces to your shader from code - need to make parameter alpha in shader as global (*'uniform'* type), and to link him across methods *'glGetUniformLocation'*, *'glUniform1f'*. For example:

```
// View-code
int mAlpha;
float alpha = 0.5f;
mAlpha = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgrammerHandle, "u_alpha");
GLES20.glUniform1f(mAlpha, alpha);

// Shader-code
...
uniform float u_alpha;
...
gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb,u_alpha);
```

But that is not all!
Need to set parameters GlSurfaceView and Render. After initialization GlSurfaceView  should be allowed a transparent Drawing:

```
setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

In render object too must to set a transparent color cleaning and correct color mixing.

```
GLES20.glClearColor ( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
GLES20.glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

Color mixing can be different. Default - colors mix i.e. `GLES20.glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);` - not necessary write.
But there are other options of mixing:

- GL_FUNC_SUBTRACT
- GL_FUNC_REVERSE_SUBTRACT

I was not write *'glBlendEquation'* in my code.

Next important moment - alpha mixing. Method *'glBlendFunc'* or *'glBlendFuncSeparate'*. More information you can read in OpenGL tutorial. For correct alpha mixing i took advantage of more detailed setup:

```
GLES20.glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
```

The last thing to do - overriding methods *'setAlpa'* and *'getAlpa'* in your GlSurfaceView.

**P.S.**  If in your View a transparent artifact appear, then you may tried to set parameters `setZOrderOnTop(true);` and/or `android:windowIsTranslucent="true"` inside XML. But for me it was not required - everything works fine!

Comment: what was your override for setAlpha and getAlpha?